# How do you get the "final" url for a facebook ad using the marketing api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

Different ad types have the url in different locations. For now I see some ads have the url in parameter `url_tags` and other have it in `adcreatives[object_story_spec][link_data][link]` are there any other locations I should be checking for to cover all ad types even instagram

Comment: there is no simple way to do this, as this will vary depending on the kind of creative. Not all creatives have an offsite link for example.

Comment: @PaulBain thanks for confirming its not simple. Do you guys have a guide or sample, if not ill start one but would love more people to add to it

Comment: I don't have one right now unfortunately

Comment: @PaulBain the main case I am struggling with is ads where the creative looks like this `{ "object_type": "SHARE", "object_story_id": "234716299905260_1018384218205127", "object_story_spec": { "page_id": "234716299905260", "template_data": { "link": "https://www.honest.com/gift/guide", "message": "Give the gift of Honest! Baskets and gift sets that are safe, stylish and convenient.", "name": "{{product.name | titleize}}", "description": "{{product.price | titleize}}", "call_to_action": { "type": "SHOP_NOW" }, "multi_share_end_card": true } }, "id": "6043265277368" }`

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you are asking for the final post URL for the Facebook placement for the ad. You can construct that using the "effective_object_story_id" field from the Facebook Ad Creative that you can get through the Marketing API. That is usually of the format: "234716299905260_1018384218205127". You can then construct the Facebook URL simply by appending "https://www.facebook.com/" to the story_id. So in this case the URL will be:

https://www.facebook.com/234716299905260_1018384218205127